# Snow Leopard + mod_rewrite = 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, macos, mod-rewrite, osx-snow-leopard

I am facing a very odd issue with Snow Leopard and Apache's mod_rewrite. I have set this up on Linux servers countless times, and it always worked. Being quite new to OS X, I'm quite puzzled.

This is my current configuration file as found in `/etc/httpd/users/username.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/"

<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now my problem is that whenever I try to access a rewritten url I get a `403 Forbidden` page. I have tried to see if there was any information in the log, but nothing is coming up, so I'm left here wondering. To be sure, my permissions seem to be fine (I have tried 755 and 775).

For reference, this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hello$ home.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^oops$ sorry.html [NC,L]
```

Just to make double sure I have set `AllowOverride All` in the main httpd.conf file (under `Directory /`).

Any advice is greatly welcome.

Thanks for your time :)

**EDIT:** I have just noticed that if I use a VirtualHost everything works as expected, so I wonder how my RewriteRules are being read by Apache...

Comment: I'm using this feature on Snow Leopard, and it's working fine. My configs are under /etc/apache2, which leads me to wonder: Are you certain your /etc/httpd/users/*.conf files are being sucked into Apache's config?

Comment: Apache config questions are better at serverfault.com.

Comment: @Mak Killbers: The error log only shows the standard startup and shutdown messages, nothing else.

@Brian Clapper: I am sure it is read because I found that file by looking at the main httpd.conf file. Also, these issues only started after I modified my user conf file.

@Graham Lee: Thanks, I'll go there if this thread doesn't yield any results.

One thing to notice is that if I use a VirtualHost everything works as expected, so I wonder how my RewriteRules are being read by Apache...